# Вырезать все смайлики из строки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим у нас есть строка:

> ```
> "‍‍‍❤‍‍✋ Какой прекрасный день!"
> ```

Как из этой строки убрать все смайлики и на выходе получить лишь чистый текст:

> ```
> "Какой прекрасный день!"
> ```

При этом смайлики могут быть совершенно разные не обязательно те что в строке.

Comment: смайлики - это обычные UTF-16 символы. Просто удали эти символы.

Comment: @Lofectr русские буквы «Какой прекрасный день» это тоже UTF-16 символы. Да что уж там, английские буквы — это тоже UTF-16 символы! Предлагаете удалить вообще весь текст?

Comment: @andreymal вы адекватный? Я сказал удалить символы, обозначающие смайлики

Comment: @Lofectr удалить символы обозначающие смайлики это и есть вопрос ;). Вопрос: "как удалить смайлики?". Ответ: "удалить символы обозначающие смайлики". ЭЭЭЭ... ???

Comment: @Lofectr собственно в этом и вся суть вопроса — как удалить символы, обозначающие смайлики?

Comment: @andreymal Ну да...

Comment: @andreymal А я понял. "Автор хотел сказать", что надо мол составить лист смайлов, и проходится по нему удаляя символы.

Comment: С какого перепуга? Кто то будет здесь, составлять лист смайликов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import re

text = u'This is a smiley face \U0001f602'
print(text) # with emoji

def deEmojify(text):
    regrex_pattern = re.compile(pattern = "["
        u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
        u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
        u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
        u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
                           "]+", flags = re.UNICODE)
    return regrex_pattern.sub(r'',text)

print(deEmojify(text))
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404752/removing-emojis-from-a-string-in-python)

А можно пожеще:

```
import re
re.sub('[^\x00-\x7Fа-яА-Я]', '', string)
```

Comment: Пробовал этот метод но он удаляет не все смайлики.

https://sun9-57.userapi.com/FaOONO5YaEB5ptalPEDCcui-19Q_Th5CsbFu5w/2wtd924Nd9w.jpg

Comment: @Cookie updated.

Comment: @Cookie `[\x00-\x7Fа-яА-Я]` ?

Comment: нет эта регулярка теперь удаляет текст вместо смайликов)

Comment: ой: `[^\x00-\x7Fа-яА-Я]` @Cookie.

Comment: @Cookie `^[A-Za-z.!@?#"$%&:;() *\+,\/;\-=[\\\]\^_{|}<>\u0400-\u04FF]*$` ?

Comment: `[^\x00-\x7Fа-яА-Я]`

Answer (score 6):

Попробуйте так:

```
# pip install emoji
import emoji

text = "‍‍‍❤‍‍✋Какой прекрасный день!"
new_text = ''.join(char for char in text if char not in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI)

print(new_text)
# ‍‍‍‍‍Какой прекрасный день!
```

Comment: Без зависимости никак не обойтись? Не хотелось бы что-бы из за такой простой вырезки целый модуль ставить

Comment: @Cookie, вытащить из этого модуля код в ваш скрипт, но вы ведь наверняка еще будете сторонние библиотеки использовать :)

Comment: @Cookie да там небось один файлик ;)

Comment: Я б ваш ответ принял ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor могу поменять ахах) Если вам так удобнее будет

Comment: @Cookie Как будет правильнее на твой взгляд. Принимать надо тот ответ, который сочтешь наилучшим (и будешь юзать в своем коде). Мне на жалко ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor твой ответ я принял потому что, не привык ставить из за маленьких задач зависимости, стараюсь для этого прибегать к стоковым модулям, какой вариант вы и показали, он работает и это главное) Не спорю этот вариант тоже скорее всего работает, но и возможно я пороноик)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, спасибо, я тоже бы его принял :D

Comment: Такой подход сломает строки со смайликами, состоящими из нескольких символов `text = '*️'`

Comment: @andreymal, интересно... Есть идеи как такое обходить? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "‍‍‍❤‍‍✋ Какой прекрасный день!"  
a = text.find('К')  # определяем начало новой строки (без смайликов)  
text_new = text[a:]  # и берем срез до конца  

print(text_new)  # Какой прекрасный день!
```

Comment: Да что уж там, можно сразу `print("Какой прекрасный день!")`